# fixed grid column while other changes

Tags: css, css-grid

I have 2 column complex grid layout, in example is just one part of it. My full code is similar to that. Is there any way, with css grid, green box will always stay near the red box, without any fixed size. if right column item has more content then left first item I want block D and block B will be next to each other without space.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "d c" "b a";
  grid-column-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
  background-color: blue;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
  background-color: green;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: purple;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
  background-color: red;
}

.block {
  /* height:300px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block a">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="block b">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.
  </div>
  <div class="block c">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi quod ea aperiam consequatur fugiat libero voluptate accusantium amet corporis laborum in, quae ratione, atque assumenda. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid
    enim labore, eaque quidem repellendus atque!
  </div>
  <div class="block d">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae blanditiis laudantium sit, pariatur omnis quibusdam?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use
grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto) in the container class and remove the
align-items: baseline; which can help you with that

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:  "d c" "b a";
  grid-column-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  /*align-items: baseline;*/
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.a {

  grid-area: a;
  background-color: blue;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
  background-color: green;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: purple;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
  background-color: red;
}

.block {
  /* height:300px; */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block a">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    
  </div>
  <div class="block b">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi quod ea aperiam consequatur fugiat libero voluptate accusantium amet corporis laborum in, quae ratione, atque assumenda. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid
    enim labore, eaque quidem repellendus atque!
    
  </div>
  <div class="block c">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi quod ea aperiam consequatur fugiat libero voluptate accusantium amet corporis laborum in, quae ratione, atque assumenda. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid
    enim labore, eaque quidem repellendus atque!
  </div>
  <div class="block d">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae blanditiis laudantium sit, pariatur omnis quibusdam?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi quod ea aperiam consequatur fugiat libero voluptate accusantium amet corporis laborum in, quae ratione, atque assumenda. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid
    enim labore, eaque quidem repellendus atque!
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tinker with `grid-template-areas`. Here's an example.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: " d c "
                       " b c "
                       " . c "
                       " . a "
                       " . a "
                       " . a ";
  grid-column-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
  background-color: blue;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
  background-color: green;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: purple;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
  background-color: red;
}

.block {
  /* height:300px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block a">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="block b">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.
  </div>
  <div class="block c">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi quod ea aperiam consequatur fugiat libero voluptate accusantium amet corporis laborum in, quae ratione, atque assumenda. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid
    enim labore, eaque quidem repellendus atque!
  </div>
  <div class="block d">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae blanditiis laudantium sit, pariatur omnis quibusdam?
  </div>
</div>
```